# PostGIS: Finding duplicate label within a radius

Tags: python, postgis, duplication

I have data in PostGIS that have value and geometry. If there is a same value within let's say <10 m, I want to detect or remove that value from my table. Here is the small example:

```
create table points (id serial primary key, val integer, label2);

select addGeometryColumn('points', 'geom', 1, 'point', 2);

insert into points (id, val, label2, geom) values
  (1, 1, aaa, st_geomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 1)),
  (2, 1, bbb, st_geomFromText('POINT(1 2)', 1)),
  (3, 1, aaa, st_geomFromText('POINT(10 100)', 1)),
  (4, 2, ccc, st_geomFromText('POINT(10 101)', 1));
```

because of data(id) 1 and 2 has the same value and distance<10m, so there just will be:

```
  id |val| source | geom 
-----+------------+------
   3 | 1 |  aaa   | xxx
   4 | 2 |  ccc   | xxx
```

Do you know how to query that in PostGIS?

Comment: Please only choose the software product as tag that is relevant for your question.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm new here and in my path for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To select:**

If you want to keep at least one (random) record of those you are trying to identify as duplicates in the selection, run

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (val, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, <threshold_in_CRS_units>, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY val))
        *
FROM    points
;
```

If you want to select only records that have no other point with the same value within `<threshold>` distance, run

```
SELECT  *
FROM    points AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    points
    WHERE   a.cat = cat AND a.id <> id AND ST_DWithin(a.geom, geom, <threshold_in_CRS_units>)
);
```

---

**To remove:**

You'd want to create a new table for the former of those two queries (and drop the old one):

```
CREATE TABLE new_points AS
  SELECT  DISTINCT ON (val, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, <threshold_in_CRS_units>, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY val))
          *
  FROM    points
  ORDER BY
          id
;
```

while the latter of those is easily adaptable as `DELETE`:

```
DELETE
FROM    points AS a
WHERE   EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    points
    WHERE   a.cat = cat AND a.id <> id AND ST_DWithin(a.geom, geom, <threshold_in_CRS_units>)
);
```

---

**Note:**

The `<threshold_...>` value in the above queries will be treated as *units of the underlying CRS*!

If not already projected, in the first query you would need to find a suitable projection with *meter* as unit, and transform the geometries, e.g. on-the-fly:

```
... ST_ClusterDBSCAN(ST_Transform(geom, <SRID>), <threshold_in_meter>, 0) ...
```

while in the second query, you have the additional option to use the `GEOGRAPHY` type to get precise, but computationally more demanding *meter* based measures from a *degree* based (geographic) reference system:

```
... ST_DWithin(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, geom::GEOGRAPHY, <threshold_in_meter>) ...
```

---

***As a bonus:***

**To aggregate:**

There are options to get aggregated values and derived geometries from the cluster of points, e.g.

```
SELECT  val,
        ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids,
        ARRAY_AGG(label2) AS labels,
        COUNT(geom) AS pt_count,
        ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
FROM    (
    SELECT  *, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, <threshold_in_CRS_units>, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY val) AS clst
    FROM    points
) q
GROUP BY
        val, clst
;
```

would create a centroid geometry of all neighboring points within the given threshold, and arrays of their respective `id` & `label2` values. I also included a point count.

Comment: Really good explanation! Could you explain more about CRS_units please? how to convert to meter?
is "a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, geom::GEOGRAPHY, <threshold_in_meter>" always convert to meter or it can be kilometer or millimeter?

Comment: @Anonymous your data should have a Coordinate Reference System assigned, most likely denoted as `EPSG` code. That reference system defines the units it uses; for a geographical reference system, the unit is *degree*. The `GEOGRAPHY` type works on these (only), and will always accept and output values in *meter*. But not all PostGIS functions accept `GEOGRAPHY`, e.g. `ST_ClusterDBSCAN`; thus, you will have to transform your data into a projection suitable for your area of interest, that uses any metric unit. This topic is too large here, so you need to dive further into projections yourself.

Comment: I have found the second query works for my small-trial dataset, but if I do with real-large dataset that have 500.000 rows the server disconnected, this is what I get:

`"The application has lost the database connection:
⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
⁃ The user session may have timed out.
Do you want to continue and establish a new session?"`

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @Anonymous `UPDATE` transactions are very ressource intensive; simply stated, the whole table is put into transitional state (into memory), to enable a `ROLLBACK`. An easy and common workaround is to create a new table with the changes instead, and drop the old one.